Where do I add/update the Brightcove configuration to add scheduling for Sitecore?
Hi I recently installed Brightcove Connector v10.1. Where do I add/update the configuration to add scheduling for Sitecore?

Have you looked at the docs? https://integrations.support.brightcove.com/sitecore/configuration.html

In order to configure Brightcove scheduler, we need to create command options available under "System/Tasks/Commands/Data Exchange" folder.
There are 2 options available to create commands in Data Exchange.

Run All Pipeline Batches Command: This is used for running multiple pipeline batches, available as child under parent folder.
Run Selected Pipeline Batches Command: This is used for running multiple pipeline batches, selected in a multilist.

You can create the command under Data Exchange folder and select the Pipeline Batches item under Brightcove tenant to run all the pipeline batches as below:

Thereafter you can attach above command to schedule as below:

Using this way, we can schedule Brightcove to sync through scheduler.
Hope this helps!!!

Thankyou Ckhanna, it worked.

Great @CHUKKAPRASAD

From the Brightcove integration document, you need to follow these steps to configure this.

In the Sitecore Launchpad, open the Content Editor.

Go to /sitecore/system/Data Exchange and right-click on Data Exchange.

In the Insert menu, click Brightcove Tenant.

Go to /sitecore/system/Data Exchange/<tenant name></tenant>. On the Content tab, in the Administration section, click Enabled.

Save the item.

In the Content Editor, go to /sitecore/system/Data Exchange/Brightcove  -  Tenant/Endpoints/Providers/Brightcove/Web API Endpoint.

In the Settings section, under Account, select the linked Brightcove Video Cloud account from the dropdown control.

Save the item.


Follow this document for more details.
https://integrations.support.brightcove.com/sitecore/configuration.html
Also, I did a similar kind of integration but for Marketo Forms. So you can refer to my blog with the step-by-step integration process of Marketo. This might help with similar kinds of steps.
https://sbhatiablogs.wordpress.com/2019/11/21/a-simple-data-exchange-framework-setup/
Hope this helps.

Yes Sumit, the above steps are required before creating the scheduler. thankyou.
